# How to import multiple csv file names as an attribute in R?

Tags: r, list, loops, csv, import

I have 650 csv files and I´m trying to use R to import their names as an attribute. I found different codes in the net that works pretty well when data is clean. My problem is my data has a lot of empty (NA) and symbols (e.g. ?, <).   Any suggestions of how to solve this problem?

This is the code that I´m using:

```
# to import data from the folder
  mydata = ldply(list.files(pattern = "csv"), function(filename) {
  dum = read.table(filename)

 # to add the filename as well on the column
  dum$filename = filename
  return(dum)
  })
```

Comment: What do you mean by *import their name as as attribute*?  An attribute in R has a very specific meaning.  It seems like you might just want `fnames <- list.files(pattern="*.csv"); setNames(lapply(fnames, read.table), fnames)` instead

Comment: How exactly does having "messy" data interfere with adding an additional column? Do you get errors or something? What precisely is the problem?

Comment: This is the error that I receive (Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings line 31 did not have 2 elements)

Comment: Hi Richard, what I meant is to have the name of the files at the end of each row as the names have the dates and I would like to use them later. So, in my case what I would like to have is x, y,z, range, "the name of the file". In this way I can use the dates in the names for later time series analysis. the code that you sent could work if I can have the fnames as column.

Comment: Try using `fill = TRUE` in your `read.table` call

Comment: Thanks Richard, now it works and I have no problem with messy data. Still don´t know how I can extract the different variables or each object independently and associate it to the name of the file? I think I need to convert it to a data.frame.